# SBT How to disable Ivy cache for a specific groupid

Tags: sbt

I have several Scala modules that I'm building with SBT. Some of them (I'll call them dependant modules) are being published to Artifactory and then used by top-level modules.

All changes to the code are done in separate git branches. When the feature (or bugfix) is done, that branch is compiled in Jenkins and then deployed to the testing instance and handed off to the QA team.

So it's possible that there will be several git branches with different code in the dependant modules.

The problem is that Ivy is caching these modules locally, so it's possible that the top-level module will be built with the dependant module from a different branch (taken from the local cache).

I've tried adding `changing()` directive to the dependency specification in `build.sbt`.

In that case Ivy is ignoring the local cache and goes to Artifactory to download the POM file every time. Then it parses the POM file, but concludes that it has the jar file with that version in the local cache and fetches the jar file from the local cache and not from Artifactory. Which isn't what I want.

Since the code in branches hasn't been integrated into the master branch at this point, it's perfectly valid that different feature branches have the same version number, but different code.

Is there a way to tell Ivy (via SBT) to ignore local cache for a certain groupid? Or a single dependency at least?

Comment: Have you tried marking the version as a SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using versioning for your dependant modules then each codebase change must produce a different version. Ivy and maven expect that once the artifact has been published with a specific version it will stay unchanged forever. That is why they are using cached files. If you want to download a fresh version from repository on every compile you should add -SNAPSHOT suffix to the dependant module version number (eg: dep-module-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Well, adding SNAPSHOT is the same as adding changing() to the dependency, as in `def appDependencies = Seq("com.foo"%"foo-api"%"1.0" changing(), ...`. That forces Ivy to fetch the POM file from the repository on every compile, but then it doesn't fetch the jar, as explained in the original post.

Comment: Have you tried following troubleshooting steps outlined in official SBT documentation? http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#General+troubleshooting+steps

Comment: You mean running update explicitely? No, because I'm not sure what happens with parallel builds in that case. I've solved my immediate problem by using sbt-dirty-money plugin which is deleting my com.foo artifacts from ivy cache before the compile begins. That works perfectly fine because ivy has to download the artifacts every time since they will not be in the cache. However, I'm not sure what would happen if I use parallel builds in Jenkins. I'm currently using only one executor, so that can't happen. And if I try to use update explicitely, I think I'd have the same problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell the majority of your problems come from not properly versioning the dependant artifacts. If your concurrent builds ask for the same artifact version but expect different content than it is a problem. You could adopt some automatic incremental version numbering scheme. That means you have to synchronize build.sbt contents with the latest artifact versions but it makes concurrent builds safe.

Comment: They aren't distinctively versioned because they live in the different (development) git branches. And every branch is its own world with the distinctive versioning inside. But not taking into account other branches. That's what development branches are supposed to be. Synchronizing version numbers is possible, but comes at a price of possible human errors, which I would like very much to avoid.

Comment: BTW, ivy can have a branch specifier for the artifact (that would do the trick for me), but I don't see a way to use that from sbt. Another approach also failed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505825/sbt-resolution-fails-with-ivy-extra-attributes