# How to test sbt resolvers

Tags: scala, sbt

On my local machine I have an ivy cache that has been filled by working on multiple projects.

A library `X` is loaded using resolver `Y` in project `A`. This same library `X` is used in project `B`, no problems resolving this library because it's in my local cache.

When one of my colleagues loads project `B` he get's the error that library `X` could not be resolved. The problem: resolver `Y` is missing.

**How can I test if my sbt project has a complete set of resolvers to resolve all dependencies without removing my ivy cache?**

Comment: To clarify, your question: You want to see on project `B` that resolver `Y` is missing, even though you got the necessary dependencies in your local cache? Am I right?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you would need something like the `sbt update` task ([being part of the list of default tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Inspect-the-Build.html#List+available+tasks)) but explicitly telling `sbt` not to use any caching to resolve the dependencies. On SNAPSHOT dependencies this seems to be the case as default given [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24510450/3165552). The first comment also points out that it might be possible to mitigate this restriction with the optional `def changing()` on the dependency declaration site.

Comment: You could inspect the [Caching and Resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html#Caching+and+Configuration) options, as proposed by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26655891/3165552)

Comment: @isi On your first question: yes, you are right.

Comment: @isi The caching and resolution options did not provide any help.

Comment: @isi I tried `update`, this just hits the cache first

Comment: You said: the caching resolution did not provide any help. Was it somehow related to [this known bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/321)?

Comment: @isi No, it's that it did not contain any new information.

Comment: Maybe you can attract a broader audience if you add the scala tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command allows you to find if you are missing any updates for the current project. Note that this will not discover any missing resolvers for your plugins.

```
commands += Command.command("testUpdate") { state =>
  val base = baseDirectory.value
  val newState = Project
    .extract(state)
    .append(Seq(ivyPaths := new IvyPaths(base, Some(base / "tmp-cache"))), state)
  val (s, _) = Project
    .extract(newState)
    .runTask(update, newState)
  s
}
```

It could be expanded by removing the directory afterwards.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks ;) but I would have a slight addition due to common conventions. `sbt tasks` lists a list of available tasks which shows that the predefined tasks all use camel casing for their names. Using hyphens strongly reminds me using maven. Having hyphens in names might even be an issue when calling the task within a build.scala file.

Comment: @isi I have changed the name based on your suggestion. As a side not: be careful not to confuse commands with tasks.

Comment: Regarding your side note: As I was reading your comment and diving into the documentation I was clear that this is not so easy to achieve and I issued a question to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Another even more elegant solution would be to investigate the SBT sources if it is easily possible to setup this behavior as a separate task. The necessary steps could be the same as in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179696/3165552).

1. Extract parameter `sbt.ivy.home` from `update` task and provide a parameterized overload for it (if this is possible)
2. Define new task testDependencies [see documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html)
3. Create tempDirectory
4. Call update(tempDirectory)
5. Gather results
6. Remove tempDirectory
7. Promote results
8. Provide a pull request ;) or an sbt plugin

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, I'll test it out

Comment: It seems `ivyPaths := new IvyPaths(baseDirectory.value, Some(baseDirectory.value / "tmp-cache"))` does the trick. Now I just need to figure out how to create a custom task that runs `update` with that setting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added a `command` as an answer but assigned the bounty to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found an admittedly simple but also a bit hacky and nonetheless working solution.
[As described here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Ivy+Home+Directory) you can setup the ivy home directory.
After setting this up it will provoke the sbt instances on your system to update **all** dependencies, due to a fresh cache directory.
When all dependencies could be resolved you could inspect the std out for some string indicating success. Like `Done updating.` and delete the temporal folder afterwards. **Caution, a fresh resolve from scratch might take a while! ~5min 100mBit/s and using an SSD drive**

Instead of defining the `sbt.ivy.home` variable system wide and in an somewhat unportable fashion i would recommend to use the less system invasive option of defining the `sbt.ivy.home` variable within the environment variable `SBT_OPTS` on your local command/terminal session. On Windows this looks as follows:

```
C:\Users\isi\Projects\learning\sbt-test-dependencies>SET SBT_OPTS=-Dsbt.ivy.home="C:\path\to\your\temp\directory"

C:\Users\isi\Projects\learning\sbt-test-dependencies>sbt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\isi\Projects\learning\sbt-test-dependencies\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/isi/Projects/learning/sbt-test-dependencies/project/}sbt-test-dependencies-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/4.0.0/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (4783ms)
...
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.5/jline-2.10.5.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.5!jline.jar (419ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.4/jansi-1.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (325ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sbt-test-dependencies (in build file:/C:/Users/isi/Projects/learning/sbt-test-dependencies/)/Users/isi/Projects/learning/sbt-test-dependencies/)
```

The output can be piped to lets say `grep` and the exit code can be used for further processing. Notice, that the console output above was produced using the interactive `sbt` command, a similar output is generated using the non interactive `sbt update` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an SBT plugin available, called [SBT dirty money](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dirty-money), to add additional functionality for tackle this problem. Although you have to execute an extra command.

Comment: "without removing my ivy cache" - plugin clears the dependencies from the cache - since you will be adding them directly again to test it won't be a problem though.

Comment: Yep, it means you have to download everything again. Making this part of the release step ensures the resolution, but it does adds several minutes of build time. What is more important, making sure that all is resolved or a quick build which might fail. 

When using build servers you might want to create an extra step for test and acceptance to test the resolvers and skip it for production.

But this is entirely your own choice.